# Which File contains the local Static IP Address in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-networking

The Operating system of a Windows XP machine has crashed.
I want to know its Static IPv4 Address, to reconfigure the system after using the *Repair Operating System* option.

How can I retrieve my old Static IP Address by using another bootable media and which file contains the IP address?

Comment: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Param eters\Interfaces

Answer (score 8):

You can check your actual IP address using following command:

```
ipconfig /all
```

In most of the cases you'll get the same IP address (if you've static address configured, also when using Auto/DHCP till your release time). You can also log in into your local router (gateway) and check the logs which IP address was assigned to you PC before (based on your MAC address which you'll find it in your ipconfig).

If you want to retrieve it using registry, run:

```
regedit
```

Then in the following registry key you'll find your IP address under your Interface GUID:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces]
```

Then you'll have something like:

```
\<Interface GUID ex: {1BBA2BE4-D734-47DF-AEDC-6167F60E278D}>
```

Then check the following keys:

```
IPAddress, SubnetMask, DefaultGateway, NameServer
```

If you don't have access to regedit, try to find it in the RAW file (searching for above keys). Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

It's `C:\Windows\System32\config\system`. You can mount it and view it with a registry editor.